# Word VBA listbox columns disappearing

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have set up the initialization of a Word VBA user form, which consists of a listbox and accept/cancel buttons, so that the first time it is run content from a Word file is loaded into an array and then into the listbox list. Subsequently, a flag is used to skip the array creation and the existing array (declared as public) is used to repopulate the listbox list. When first run all three columns of data appear. But when rerun, only the first column appears. The data in the nonvisible columns is still there (that is, the macro runs correctly), it just doesn't appear to display. The form also works perfectly if the if-then is commented out. Does anyone have ideas for getting the columns to display?

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

If QueryArrayFlag = False Then
    Dim sourcedoc As Document
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim myitem As Range
    Dim m As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim FileName As String

    FilePath = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.Path & Application.PathSeparator
    FileName = "PresetQueries.docx"
    Set sourcedoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=FilePath & FileName)
    i = sourcedoc.tables(1).Rows.Count - 1
    j = 3
    QueryListBox.ColumnCount = j
    QueryListBox.ColumnWidths = "20;60;750"
    ReDim QueryArray(i, j)
    For n = 0 To j - 1
        For m = 0 To i - 1
            Set myitem = sourcedoc.tables(1).cell(m + 2, n + 1).Range
            myitem.End = myitem.End - 1
            QueryArray(m, n) = myitem.Text
        Next m
    Next n
    sourcedoc.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    QueryArrayFlag = True
End If

QueryListBox.List() = QueryArray
QueryListBox.ListIndex = 0

End Sub
```

Comment: Was `sourcedoc` closed after `UserForm_Initialize`? Whereelse does `QueryArray` gets changed? Or move the `QueryListBox.ColumnWidths` out of the if-block?

Comment: Sourcedoc is closed just before the end of the if-then branch, after work with the source file ends.The QueryArray content is never changed; the only action involving it is assigning the selected row to a variable. Moving the columnwidth definition out of the loop (before or after it) doesn't result in any correction of the problem.

Comment: Moving "QueryListBox.ColumnCount = j" out of the loop and revising it to read "QueryListBox.ColumnCount = 3" does resolve the problem, though it isn't clear why (since that shouldn't affect only the display). So the problem appears to be resolved.